# S3 PHP access denied put object in one bucket but success in other bucket

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use PHP to `put` a file into an s3 bucket, but I'm getting an `Access Denied` error.   I'm pretty sure the issue is related to the bucket configuration and not my code or the IAM user policy because I did the following experiments

1. I use the `key_id` and `key_secret` of the root user
2. I perform `<?php $S3->putObjectFile` to the bucket `new-bucket`
3. I get `Access Denied` error
4. I perform `<?php $S3->putObjectFile` to the bucket `old-bucket` which is a bucket I've successfully written to in the past
5. I get success and confirm that file is properly uploaded
6. I create a new IAM user with the appropriate write policies to both the `new-bucket` and the `old-bucket`
7. I perform steps 2 to 5 with the new IAM user and **get the same results** and get the same results as the root user.
8. I open S3 Browser on my computer
9. I insert the `key_id` and `key_secret` of root user
10. I upload file to `new-bucket`.
11. I get success.
12. I upload file to `old-bucket`.
13. I get success.
14. I insert the `key_id` and `key_secret` of the IAM user.
15. I perform the steps 10 to 14 and **get the same results** as the root user.
16. I go to S3 website and review what is different between the configurations of the `old-bucket` vs. the `new-bucket`.  The only differences I can see are that the bucket names are different and the regions are different.  They both have these permissions:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

---

I conducted a few more experiments.

17. I went to S3 website
18. I pressed the `Create Bucket` button
19. I typed `new-bucket-2` into the name of the bucket and I chose `us-west-2` as the region (which is same as `old-bucket`).
20. I pressed `Copy settings from another bucket` and I chose `old-bucket`.
21. I pressed Save.
22. I updated the policies of the IAM user to be abel to write to the `new-bucket-2`.
23. Both the root user and the IAM user will get Access Denied when `<?php $S3->putObjectFile` to `new-bucket-2`.
24. Both the root user and the IAM user can write to `new-bucket-2` via the S3 Browser on my computer.

Also note, the `old-bucket` was made many years ago.  Not sure if that makes a difference?

Comment: What are the bucket policies on the two buckets?

Comment: Let me know if I'm looking at the right place for the bucket policy.  But under the `Permissions>Bucket Policy` they are both empty, as shown in the images above.  Are they set somewhere else?